# I have a text file with a list of files I need copied how do I do this?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, find

I have a text file that has a list of files with each file name on a new line. Those files exist in multiple subfolders. I need to copy those files to a separate folder where all of the files that I'm copying will reside. How do I do this?

I've looked at the find command but I cannot see how to open a file and have it look through it to find the files it will need to find so they can be copied.

Comment: Just the file names, or directory/filename? If the latter, `xargs` and `cp --target-directory` will help. Read `man xargs  cp`.

Comment: If there are not too many files to be copied, you may be fine with `cp --target-directory SEPARATE_FOLDER $(cat TEXTFILE)`. The `$(...)` construct executes the command within the parentheses and is replaced by that command's output. In this case, `cat TEXTFILE` lists the files you want to copy. If TEXTFILE is too large, it can overflow the space reserved for command line arguments. In such cases, the `xargs` command mentioned by @waltinator helps.

Comment: @berndbausch I don't think we should be encouraging constructs like `$(cat TEXTFILE)` in this context since the expansion will be subject to word splitting and globbing

Comment: Show the example of few lines from list, few desired "output" paths and something ypu attempted first.

Comment: There are only 300 filenames in the file so it shouldn't be too many.  Here is an example of the filenames but it is one per line: 
DSCF5414.RAF
DSCF5421.RAF
DSCF5465.RAF
DSCF5472.RAF
DSCF5486.RAF
DSCF5495.RAF
DSCF5509.RAF
DSCF5560.RAF
DSCF5610.RAF